# How can I undo this (accidental) table inheritance in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, single-table-inheritance

I've got a django app library in production, and have found a major flaw.

The library declares `AbstractMyModel` from which a concrete `MyModel` inherits. Users of the library can choose to install the app and use MyModel directly, or just import the abstract models to do their own thing with.

The problem is that **`AbstractMyModel` isn't abstract.** I forgot to include a `class Meta()` declaring `abstract=True`.

So I basically have a table inheritance in production:

```py
class AbstractMyModel(models.Model):
    """Abstract model... EXCEPT IT'S NOT!!!"""

    name = models.SlugField(
        help_text="name",
        unique=True,
    )


class MyModel(AbstractMyModel):
    """ARGH - the abstract one isn't actually abstract
    But I've got this in production - there are two actual tables from
    AbstractMyModel and MyModel. How can I sort this mess out?"""
```

**QUESTION: How would I migrate my way out of this, to collapse the inheritance and end up with the MyModel table as concrete and AbstractMyModel as truly abstract?**

TIA!

### **EDIT**

Question found to be a duplicate of [Migrate from multi-table inheritance model to abstract base classes in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355459/migrate-from-multi-table-inheritance-model-to-abstract-base-classes-in-django)

I've voted to close.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355459/migrate-from-multi-table-inheritance-model-to-abstract-base-classes-in-django - you can do this by creating a set of temporary models into which you copy your data. You then delete the existing models and redefine them to use the abstract class, and copy the data back into them.